# How can I use a string which is a date and check if it is today

Tags: javascript, html

How can I use a string which is a date and check if it is today

I have the following hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" id="datThe" value="01192015" />
```

How can I check to see if `01192015` is today.

UPDATE (not working):

```
<input type="hidden" value="closeHuguenot" id="statHuguenot" />
<input type="hidden" value="01232015" id="dateHuguenot" />

$(function () {
    var date = new Date(); // Initiate a new date object
    var day = date.getDate(); // Gets the current day
    day = (day.length < 2) ? day : '0' + day; // This will add 0 before the date if its less than 10
    var month = date.getMonth() + 1; // Because js months starts at 0
    month = (month.length < 2) ? month : '0' + month; // Will add 0 before the month if less than 10
    var year = date.getFullYear(); // Gets the current year
    var formatted_date = month + day + year; // Puts them together as your date is formatted

    var sHuguenot = $("#statHuguenot").val();
    var dHuguenot = $("#dateHuguenot").val();
    if (sHuguenot.toLowerCase() == "closehuguenot" && dHuguenot == formatted_date.toString()) {
        $("#Label171").html("CLOSED"); //not displaying closed...
    }
});
```

Comment: parse the date and compare it to `new Date()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var date = new Date(); // Initiate a new date object
var day = date.getDate(); // Gets the current day
day = ( day > 10 ) ? day : '0' + day; // This will add 0 before the date if its less than 10
var month = date.getMonth()+1; // Because js months starts at 0
month = ( month > 10 ) ? month : '0' + month; // Will add 0 before the month if less than 10
var year = date.getFullYear(); // Gets the current year
var formatted_date = month + day + year; // Puts them together as your date is formatted

// Check if the current date is equal to your input value
if( document.getElementById('datThe').value == formatted_date.toString() ){
    alert( ' The date is today ' );
}
```

Comment: Won't `month + day + year` produce a number here? :)

Comment: Isn't that what I need to compare with the hidden value?

Comment: `''+ month + date + year` this would fix it

Comment: This is what I did: `var formatted_date = "" + month + day + year;` and then compared like this: `var dTheall = $("#dateTheall").val(); dTheall == formatted_date;` Is that going to work?

Comment: you are right @BatuZet I corrected my answer thus by adding .toString(). I also forgot to add 0 before day and months on those returning a singly number

Comment: @OleHaugset I updated my question and for some reason it is not working. Any idea :/

Comment: Thats because Im a tad drunk and miswrote. Updated answer again =) Will give you date 23 instead of 023 ;)